# List of questions within favorite tags

Tags: feature-request

I have a whole bunch of tags that I have set as favorite. I would like to see a way to list new questions that are asked within these tags. Currently the only way of doing this is to click on each tag. This has kind of annoyed me for a while.

Right now we have question tabs:

- newest
- featured
- frequent
- votes
- active
- unanswered

Why not add a favorite?

<sub>(I'm not sure if this should be on Meta Stack Exchange or Meta Stack Overflow. My last question got moved here, see if this one gets moved there :))</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put your favourite tags in the searchbox like this

```
[tag1] or [tag2] or [tag3]
```

to see only questions with these tags*. Then you can sort them by newest or whatever you like.

<sub>* If you bookmark this page you will always have access to it.</sub>

Comment: very nice. I hadn't seen that before.  This seams to work as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter+or+google-analytics  I need to make myself a really long link for bookmark :)

Comment: How did you get that t-shirt? :D

Comment: What @MarounMaroun said

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I won it in a contest like this one: [what-happens-when-you-plug-a-ups-into-itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231739/)

Comment: wouldn't it be nice if they had a link next to the "Favorite Tags
 edit " to this huge link I'm building now.

Comment: @BTW you can use wildcards if that helps you. `[sql*]` for instance will add all sql tags to you search box automatically.